# Non-numeric elements in banded sparse array

Tags: sparse-arrays

The documentation mentions that "the elements in `SparseArray` need not be numeric", although "the individual elements of a sparse array cannot themselves be lists." I was wondering what type of objects can be put in a sparse array, as it also appears that sparse arrays themselves cannot be. That said, the documentation also says that "`ArrayReshape` works with `SparseArray` objects," which would suggest that sparse arrays should be able to contain sparse arrays (or lists or vice versa).

What I am trying to do is make a sparse block-banded (Toeplitz) matrix, where the block matrix has the same banding as the blocks (nested or fractal-like). Ideally, I would just be able to do:

```
Block[{k = 4, h}, 
   h[ht_] := 
    SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> ht, Band[{2, 1}] -> ht/4, 
       Band[{1, 2}] -> ht/4}, {k, k}];
   ArrayFlatten[
    h[h[1]]]]
```

However, it gives the error that "insufficient positions are available in the `Band[<>]` to fit all the values `SparseArray[<>]`..."

It seems I need some way to get pretend it is a scalar. It seems wrapping it in a `Hold` allows it to form the sparse array `h[Hold[h[1]]`, but then to actually `ReleaseHold` requires converting the sparse array to a normal one. That is `ReleaseHold[h[Hold[h[1]]]]` will not actually release the hold on the internal elements of the outer sparse array (and thus, `ArrayFlatten`ing it doesn't give the desired result). So I need to `ArrayFlatten[ReleaseHold[Normal[h[Hold[h[1]]]]]]`

The trouble with using `Normal` to unsparsify the matrix (so that `ReleaseHold` will work) is that it isn't feasible for large `k`. There are a few other approaches I tried (such as using an undefined `f` or converting the inner sparse matrices `ToString`s), however they all have the same trouble of requiring `Normal` to undo this.

So to reiterate the question, can `SparseArray` take sparse arrays as elements and how can I get it to treat it as a scalar (when used with `Band`)?

Answer (score 5):

"can SparseArray take sparse arrays as elements?" simple answer no.

You can make a single `SparseArray` of whatever depth you want though, eg for your example:

```
SparseArray[{{k_, k_, i_, i_} -> 1,
             {k_, k_, i_, j_} /; (Abs[j - i] == 1 ) -> 1/4,
             {i_, j_, k_, k_} /; (Abs[j - i] == 1 ) -> 1/4  , 
             {i_, j_, k_, l_} /; (Abs[j - i] == 1 && Abs[k - l] == 1  ) -> 
                    1/16 }, {4, 4, 4, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: That's a pity. Sadly, your suggested approach is a fair bit slower than what I had suggested (at least for k=1024 my approach takes 8 seconds, while your approach will take that long for k=40). Originally, I was hitting memory issues (at k=40) although that must have been with a slight different positioning of `Normal` (as it must have been unsparsifying the entire $40^2\times40^2$ matrix); however, it works well enough now, for the parameter range that I need.